# Como ordenas dos arreglos diferentes

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Se ordenar un arreglo numerico, que queden de menor a mayor. El problema es que tengo dos arreglos, uno el cual es numerico y el otro es de tipo char.

Lo que quisiera es que al momento de ordenar el arreglo numerico y el de caracteres. Las letras queden en la misma posicion que su valor numerico.

Este es el codigo:

```
introducir el código aquí
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int n,m;

cin>>n;

int arr[n];
char brr[n];

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
    cin>>brr[i];
}

cin>>m;

int i,u;

for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
    cin>>i;
    cin>>u;
}

}
```

Este es un ejemplo de los valores que se agregan al ejecutar el programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer numero es "5" el cual es el tamaño de los dos arreglos, tanto numerico como el de caracteres.

El segundo valor que es "3" el intervalo que quiero que tenga. Como ejemplo es el primero "0 a 6".

Lo que a mi me interesa es que al momento de ordenar el primer arreglo: ejemplo el "1" esta relacionado con su "R". Como le hago para que al momento de ordenar el arreglo numerico la "R" del arreglo de caracteres la "R" siga estando relacionada con el "1" y asi sucesivamente con los demas numeros y caracteres.

Comment: La pregunta correcta sería: **Cómo ordenar un arreglo en función de otro**. Por cierto, tu código no debería compilar puesto que el tamaño de un arreglo debe conocerse en tiempo de compilación.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que planteas, puedes usar [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Es una estructura que brinda stl, que relaciona dos elementos al igual que un diccionario en C#, Python u otros lenguajes (como un par clave-valor). Además los ordena según su clave.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main(){

    std::map<int, char> diccionario;
    
    // Puedes insertar elementos con insert o el operador []
    diccionario.insert({1, 'R'});
    diccionario[3] = 'B';

    // O crear elementos evitando copiar con emplace. Útil con clases
    diccionario.emplace(4, 'B');

    // Recorrer el diccionario
    for (const auto& [clave, valor] : m) 
    {
        std::cout << '[' << clave << "] = " << valor << "; ";
    }

    // Borrar una clave
    diccionario.erase(3);

    // Borrar todos los elementos
    diccionario.clear();
}
```